# How do you stop BeginForm() from referencing an area in ASP.NET Core MVC application?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am creating a contact page that is outside of any areas, but when I use the `@Html.BeginForm` helper, it continues to add the name of one of my areas.

My controller is at /contact/index

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var contactForm = new ContactFormViewModel();
            return View(contactForm); 
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SendEmail(ContactFormViewModel contactFormInfo)
        {
            // send email code
            return View();
        }
}
```

My `Index` view for contact:

```
@model ContactFormViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Contact";
    ViewData["PageName"] = "contact_index";
    ViewData["Heading"] = "<i class='fal fa-info-circle'></i> Contact";
    ViewData["PageDescription"] = "Please reach out and let us know how you're doing";
}

<div class="fs-lg fw-300 p-5 bg-white border-faded rounded mb-g">

    @using (@Html.BeginForm("SendEmail", "Contact", new { area = "" }))
    {
        // Name
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName, "First Name")
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        // Email
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, "Email")
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        // Category
        <div class="form-group">
            @{
                var list = new List<SelectListItem>()
                {
                    new SelectListItem("Common", ContactFormViewModel.InquiryType.Common.ToString()),
                    new SelectListItem("Question", ContactFormViewModel.InquiryType.Question.ToString()),
                    new SelectListItem("Error", ContactFormViewModel.InquiryType.Error.ToString()),
                    new SelectListItem("Advertising", ContactFormViewModel.InquiryType.Advertising.ToString()),
                    new SelectListItem("Other", ContactFormViewModel.InquiryType.Other.ToString()),
                };

            }
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ContactType, "Contact Type")
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ContactType, list, new { @class = "form-control"})
        </div>
        // Body
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Message, "Message")
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        // Submit
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    }

</div>
```

Clicking 'Submit' always posts back to: `/fantasyfootball/Contact/SendEmail`

```
<form action="/fantasyfootball/Contact/SendEmail" method="post"></form>
```

Not sure this matters, but here is my startup.cs route configuration:

```
// Route for printable sheets since they have the /cheatsheet/ static portion
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "FantasyFootballPrintable",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=printable}/cheatsheet/{action=index}");

// The generic route for the Fantasy Football Route
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "FantasyFootball",
                    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=cheatsheet}/{action=custom}/{id?}");

// Setting the default route in the area
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "DefaultFantasyFootball",
                    pattern: "{area=fantasyfootball}/{controller=cheatsheet}/{action=custom}/{id?}");

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=HtmlHelper}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may put the `default` endpoint at the top. Actually, before `DefaultFantasyFootball`

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=HtmlHelper}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "FantasyFootballPrintable",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=printable}/cheatsheet/{action=index}");

// The generic route for the Fantasy Football Route
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "FantasyFootball",
    pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=cheatsheet}/{action=custom}/{id?}");

// Setting the default route in the area
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "DefaultFantasyFootball",
    pattern: "{area=fantasyfootball}/{controller=cheatsheet}/{action=custom}/{id?}");
```

Comment: This solution worked.  It looks like the helper uses the first non-ignore route to generate links.  If it turns out reordering the routes messes with my existing navigation, I'll have to use BeginRouteForm as @Tomato32 suggested

Answer (score 1):

You can use BeginRouteForm method instead of BeginForm method.
It will generate the action link:

> form action="/Contact/SendEmail" method="post"

Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
@model MvcCore5.ViewModels.ContactFormViewModel
@{
    
}

<div class="fs-lg fw-300 p-5 bg-white border-faded rounded mb-g">

    @using (Html.BeginRouteForm(
         routeName: "default",
         method: FormMethod.Post,
         routeValues: new { action = "SendEmail", controller = "Contact", area = "" }
         ))
    {
        // Name
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FirstName, "First Name")
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        // Email
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, "Email")
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>        
        // Body
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Message, "Message")
            @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message, new { @class = "form-control" })
        </div>

        // Submit
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    }

</div>
```